# In hydroboration oxidation reaction .. why do not we use sodium hydroxide alone as a nuclophile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilicity, organoboron-compounds

Why do not we use sodium hydroxide alone as a nuclophile instead of using hydrogen peroxide along with sodium hydroxide

Comment: It converts the borate ester into alcohol. So it's important part of the reaction.

Comment: Care to expand on how it does this? A mechanism diagram showing the key steps would be good.

Answer (score 4):

The combination of hydroxide and peroxide is essential for the oxidation of boranes to alcohol, both components are needed. Firstly the hydroxide deprotonates peroxide to give peroxide anion  - a good nucleophile - which attacks the empty orbital of the R-BH2 borane giving a negatively charged boron species. Then the pair of electrons in the C–B bond migrates to oxygen, leading to breakage of C–B and formation of C–O, along with rupture of the O–O bond. Finally hydroxide ion attacks the empty p orbital of boron, the O–B bond breaks and the alkoxide anion picks up a proton from water to give the product alcohol.

Images from [here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/03/28/hydroboration-of-alkenes-the-mechanism/)

[image]

[image]

[image]